# How to know what module a package is included in?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-module

I'm not yet too familiar with Java modules, but want to dive in a bit deeper. However, when modularizing an existing application, two questions arise for me:

1. How do I know what exact modules my application has to require?
2. How do I know if a certain package is contained in a module and if so, what is its name?

Take the example of a plain, empty Spring Boot project with Spring Reactive Web dependency. By default, only these two classes are imported:

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
```

Now how do I know (1) if these classes are part of any module at all (in the case of Spring they for sure are) and (2) what exact modules I need to `require` in `module-info.java`?

Comment: Do you want to find this out programmatically or is this your scouting work before you start coding?

Comment: Before / while coding. Say I have a functioning Java application and I want to make it a module (e.g. because I want to use `jlink` to package a custom JRE), how can I find out the modules my application depends on?

Comment: I think you need to start with [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jdeps.htm#JSWOR690)

Comment: But doesn't `jdeps` only list the dependency hierarchy of an already existing module? In my case, I still need to create the module in the first place.

Comment: Please check the docs. `jdeps` is available since Java 8. It's not just for modules, it analyzes dependencies among classes and can tell you about class dependencies (including jar-level views)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven, make sure to use an updated version of the maven-compiler-plugin (like 3.8.1).

Then create the module-info.java in the src/main/java directory. As soon as you create it and try to build it, the compiler itself will tell that you're including a package that is not declared in the module-info.java

You can also use the following command to get the module name of your dependencies:

```
mvn compile org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:resolve -DexcludeTransitive
```

TLDR: Include the module-info and follow the build process, it will tell you what you need to include.

Comment: This does not explain how to know which module names must be included in the module-info.java to get a working build.